# What is the best way to represent a C array in Erlang?

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

What is the best way to represent a C array in Erlang?  I plan on passing a C array to Erlang using NIF.  The array is composed of bytes and I'll need to modify some of the bytes as the program runs.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erlang is pretty good when dealing with binaries(essentially byte arrays right?)

check it out here: http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html

Answer (score 4):

If function in NIF not reallocate array than you can represent you array as a tuple with two elements - raw pointer and elements count.